Different answers of Electrostatic Field using two methods of infinitely long sheet
If I consider a infinitely long sheet of width $w$ and it is placed in $x-y$ plane (center at origin and infinite in $y$-direction).
At a point $(0,0,z)$, the field comes out to be $$4k\sigma\arctan(w/2z)$$ which is correct ($\sigma$ is charge density).
Now If I consider a infinite long rod, its Electrostatic Field at a point $(0,0,z)$ comes out to be $2k\lambda/z$.
Now, if I consider the limit in which $w$ previously approaches zero such that the sheet tends to become a rod, then the field approaches to zero.
Why is this happening?

$\sigma$ depends on the width too, so you are ignoring the effect that $w\to 0$ is having on the charge density.

Got it. Thanks.

You have to take the limit in the "right" way.  As it is, the way you're taking the limit, the total amount of charge goes to zero.
Write the area charge density as $\sigma = \frac{Q}{wL}$, where $L$ is the length of the object (which is "very large"). We want to take the limit in such a way that $Q$ and $L$ remain constant, while $w\to 0$. Thus, we want to take the limit
$$
\lim_{w\to0}4k\sigma\arctan\left(\frac{w}{2z}\right)\,.
$$
If we naively take the limit here, we get zero, because the limit of the arctan function is 0. However, if we replace $\sigma$ by its correct expression
$$
\lim_{w\to0}4k\frac{Q}{wL}\arctan\left(\frac{w}{2z}\right) = \frac{4kQ}{2Lz}
=\frac{2k\lambda}{z}\,,
$$
because the limit of $\frac{1}{w}\arctan(w/2z)$ is $1/2z$.

Got it. Thanks.
